# I am not able to bind non local IP address to socket

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Socket  socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

        string GETrequest = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 172.16.9.251\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nUser-Agent: CSharpTests\r\n\r\n";

        IPEndPoint g_source = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.9.251"), 0);//not my local ip address

        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,  //Applies only to IP packets
                     SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include header
                           true);

        //when we bind I getting error for "The requested address is not valid in its context"
        socket.Bind(g_source);

        socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.9.251"), 80));

        socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GETrequest), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GETrequest).Length,SocketFlags.None);
        socket.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: First test, use IPAddress.Any instead of IPAddress.Parse("172.16.9.251"). Probably you set the wrong IP address. You cannot listen at port 0.

Comment: I have formatted your code, it was a mess. Please do it properly next time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you mean this one:

```
IPEndPoint g_source = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.9.251"), 80);
```

instead of

```
IPEndPoint g_source = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.9.251"), 0);
```

If you use port 0, system will assign you random port between 1024-5000.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. But issue is not for port it is for ip address. currently it is my ip and working fine because it is local ip. But when i replace it by gmail.com ip like 216.58.197.37 it gives error mentioned above.

Comment: Hi all, I want to spoofing the ip addres.

Comment: You cannot use other than your own IP. What you can do is using 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, or your real IP in windows settings, for example 192.168.1.10. If you are using IP from google, you can "Connect" to it, but you cannot "Bind" on it. You are not even in Google subnet.

Comment: Hi  Stanley, Is any other ways to spoof the ip?

Comment: Disconnect from the internet and you can do what you want, build your own network